Xamarin Forms app freezes on Splashscreen during debugging
I'm trying to debug a Xamarin Forms App on a Android Emulator but it always freezes on the Splash-Screen. Does somebody know why this happens?
This is the last version we deploy with Xamarin Forms after that we switch to flutter. But we need this version to prepare for the switch.

Target framework: .NET standard 2.0
Target Android version: Android 14.0 (API level 34)
Compile using Android version: Android 13.0 (can't select anything higher)
Use Fast Deployment (deactivated)
Advanced Android Options - Supported architectures: armeabi-v7a;x86_64;arm64-v8a
Visual Studio 2022: Version 17.12.2
Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro - API 33

Start debugging Android application ...
> am start -D -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.test.testing/crc6482ec456c74a2c136.SplashActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.testing/crc6482ec456c74a2c136.SplashActivity }
[.Testing] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[.Testing] Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
[.Testing] Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64.
[.Testing] Known variants: atom, sandybridge, silvermont, kabylake, default
[CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10175; state: ENABLED
[System.out] Sending WAIT chunk
[System.out] Debugger has connected
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] waiting for debugger to settle...
[System.out] debugger has settled (1387)
[nativeloader] Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.test.testing
[ziparchive] Unable to open '/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
[ziparchive] Unable to open '/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
[nativeloader] Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~BFtrfUGM32UOgD29gClmkA==/com.test.testing-SQIu3WS69LUgA4mgbcwTKA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.test.testing
[GraphicsEnvironment] ANGLE Developer option for 'com.test.testing' set to: 'default'
[GraphicsEnvironment] ANGLE GameManagerService for com.test.testing: false
[GraphicsEnvironment] Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.test.testing/files/.__override__`
[.Testing] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:49376,embedding=1
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll
Loaded assembly: Testing.App.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: AutoMapper.dll [External]


I have same thing. Seems like a VS problem, see this issue

I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-Bit) - LTSC 17.8 Version 17.8.16. With this Version the debugging worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@BluePalmTree, yes, the previous versions (<17.12.0) work fine, this is mentioned in the issue. I am successfully using 17.11.5 now
